# Не отправляет письмо на почту

Tags: javascript, php

выдаёт ошибку еррор использую phpmailer
всё варианты пробовал! поменял порти, gmail yandex mail ? но не получается в чем проблема?

```
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'metrex14@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxx'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('metrex14@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('sheyhan1426@gmail.com');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' оставил заявку, его телефон ' .$phone. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$email;
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это рабочий код для отправки с яндекса: 
PhpMailer-6.0.5

```
    //PhpMailer-6.0.5
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                            
    try {
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                
        $mail->isSMTP();                                     
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.ru';  
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                           
        $mail->Username = 'xxx@yandex.ru';                
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';                         
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
        $mail->Port = 587;                                  

        $mail->setFrom('xxxxx@yandex.ru', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress('xxxxx@mail.ru', 'Joe User');     
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.mail.ru";
```